# Are questions like "what is this sample", "what is this instrument" allowed here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Say I'm a fan of artist *X* who made a song *Y*. There is a sample used in song *Y* and I'm wondering where it is from.

A similar but perhaps slightly different question would be asking about an instrument used by artist *X* to make song *Y*.

Are these kind of questions on topic?

Comment: I hope these will be, as they are off topic over on Music Practice and Theory.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Identify this song/ genre / artist" - on topic?](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/34/identify-this-song-genre-artist-on-topic)

Comment: I believe this is a similar but different question than that one, @MatthewRead

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate either. The other question is much more broad. This would be targeted to specific points in a song.

Comment: Example question: [“Waking up to find your love's not real” in “Right Here, Right Now”](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/260/47)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, I believe these would be on-topic.

I would consider these specific, answerable questions, as long as they are specific to a time/song. Also, there are two such questions upvoted in the Area 51 proposal:

- [Which electronic instrument is used to produce the sound at the beginning of "Good Vibrations" by the Beach Boys?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans/61954#61954)
- [Which percussion instrument is used to make the scratching sound in the intro of "Spill the Wine" by Eric Burdon and War?](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans/65840#65840)

Answer (score 10):

Let the community decide.

On Music: Practice & Theory they are off topic (Like Rory said) (The only other SE site concerning Music)

So, I would say yes, they should be on topic here.