# Are Sample Identification Questions On Topic?

Tags: discussion

Regarding this question: [In Michael Jackson's song Thriller, what is the bird cry at 3:11?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2326/in-michael-jacksons-song-thriller-what-is-the-bird-cry-at-311)

This questions seems to be asking for identification of a sample used in the song.  Are this questions on topic?

Comment: Related: http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/46/are-questions-like-what-is-this-sample-what-is-this-instrument-allowed-here

Comment: At last check, the community seemed to be in favor of allowing them.  While that particular question is a little out of the boundary of what the previous discussion was about, I'd still allow it.

Answer (score 2):

*Just answering to remove this question from the unanswered list.*

---

Yes, questions asking to identify a sample used in a song are considered on-topic. Such questions are to use the [identify-this-sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-sample) tag (but **not** the [sample](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sample) or [sampling](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sampling) tags). Questions without enough details/research may be closed, though.

The current site policy (as of the date of this answer) on which ID questions are allowed can be seen here: [Identification questions in general. What is allowed, and what is not?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221/3955)